# Getting input from user - What are the bad smells in this code?

Tags: java, refactoring

i'm new at coding, I would like an example on how could I make transform these lines to one or more functions... I'm doing my first experiment with Constructor, and I think these lines shouldn't be in my Main(?). Thank you!

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Inserisci il codice, il nome e l'autore del libro che desideri inserire:\n");
                            //Insert book's code, name and author you want to add

                            //code 
        System.out.println("Codice (in numeri):");   //I would like to make a function from here to scan3
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = scan.nextInt();

                            //name
        System.out.println("Nome:");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = scan2.nextLine();

                            //author
        System.out.println("Autore:\n");
        Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = scan3.nextLine();

        Libro book = new Libro (c, n, a);
        System.out.println("Codice: ["+ book.codice + "] Nome: [" + book.nome + "] Autore: [" + book.autore +"]\n" );

                            //Do you want to add a new book?yes/no
        System.out.println("Desideri inserire un nuovo libro?si/no");
        Scanner risposta = new Scanner(System.in);
        risp = risposta.nextLine();

    }while (risp.equals("si") || risp.equals("Si"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some **Bad Smell**s in your code. If a bad smell is new to your ears, I could say they are some bad codes that make your code *dirty* and unreadable and also hard to maintain and develop which were first introduced by Martin M. Fowler. I suggest you take a look at his website. 

One of your code's bad smells in Naming Smell. `a`, `n`, `c` are not good names for variables while they can easily be like `name`, `codice` and `autore`.

Second bad smell in your code is "Duplicate Code" which means that similar codes exist in more than one place. In your code, you have very similar codes to get input from the user. You can get input by the following method:

```
public static getInputFormUser(String withMessage){
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(withMessage);
    return scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Now your code should like this:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Inserisci il codice, il nome e l'autore del libro che desideri inserire:\n");
    int codice = Integer.parse(getInputFormUser("Codice (in numeri): "));
    String nome = getInputFormUser("Nome: ");
    String autore = getInputFromUser("Autore: ");
    Libro book = new Libro (codice, nome, autore);
    System.out.println("Codice: ["+ book.codice + "] Nome: [" + book.nome + "] Autore: [" + book.autore +"]\n" );

                        //Do you want to add a new book?yes/no
    String risp = getInputFormUser("Desideri inserire un nuovo libro?si/no");

}while (risp.equals("si") || risp.equals("Si"));
```

Also, you can create a method to get the whole `Libro` instances with one call.  And  instead of printing `book` object that way, you can override `toString()` method in `Libro` class like this:

```
public String toString (){
    return "Codice: ["+ this.codice + "] Nome: [" + this.nome + "] Autore: [" +             
                 this.autore +"]";
}
```

and just call `System.out.println(book);` because it calls `.toString()` on every object.

Answer (score 1):

Declare one scanner and make it a member of the class instead of a local variable. Then, use these methods:

```
private int promptInt(String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt); 
    return scan.nextInt();
}

private String promptString(String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return scan.nextLine();
}
```

Then you can modify your code to utilize these methods. For example,

```
System.out.println("Codice (in numeri):");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int c = scan.nextInt();
```

can be replaced with

```
int c = promptInt("Codice (in numeri):");
```

Use the promptString method for when you need to prompt a string from the user.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. What if the next phase is to scan boolean, double, and other data types? Will you make a function for each data type?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to take an object of your class and return it after filling it with user-given information like this:

```
//INPUT FUNCTION
Libro getInput(){
       System.out.println("Codice (in numeri):");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = scan.nextInt();

                            //name
        System.out.println("Nome:");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = scan2.nextLine();

                            //author
        System.out.println("Autore:\n");
        Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = scan3.nextLine();

     return new Libro(c,n,a);

}



//START YOUR MAIN FUNCTION HERE
do {
        System.out.println("Inserisci il codice, il nome e l'autore del libro che desideri inserire:\n");
        Libro book = getInput();
        System.out.println("Codice: ["+ book.codice + "] Nome: [" + book.nome + "] Autore: [" + book.autore +"]\n" );

                            //Do you want to add a new book?yes/no
        System.out.println("Desideri inserire un nuovo libro?si/no");
        Scanner risposta = new Scanner(System.in);
        risp = risposta.nextLine();

    }while (risp.equals("si") || risp.equals("Si"));
}
```

Comment: While the main function should be minimal but this should be enough at your stage.
Always make sure to name your variables appropriately. The  names like ```c, n, a``` are bad in programming